# Homestead Installaton

Tags: bash, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

According to the docu

"Once you have cloned the Homestead repository, run the bash init.sh command from the Homestead directory to create the Homestead.yaml configuration file. The Homestead.yaml file will be placed in the ~/.homestead hidden directory:

bash init.sh"

In Windows how do I run init.sh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run `init.bat`, it will do all the job for you. `init.bat` is a Windows version of init.sh.